# What are nouns like "fish" and "craft" called?

Tags: word-request, irregular-forms

From this question: [Why is 'aircrafts' bad English, while 'crafts' is okay?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/119260/why-is-aircrafts-bad-english-while-crafts-is-okay)

What those words (like "fish") have in common is they have two different plural forms: for example, "fish" has "fish" and "fishes". "Craft" has "craft" and "crafts". Rather than I'm worried about how to use those different forms, I just want to know what those kind of words are called.

Comment: I don't think there is any special name for them, other than "really irritating to ELL students"  :)

Answer (score 2):

Nouns that have irregular plurals, such as fish, aircraft, mouse, man, are called  "irregular nouns" or "irregular plural nouns".   The phrase "irregular nouns" is more common.

Answer (score 1):

As stated in [this answer from EL&U](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/45040/2303), such nouns are referred to as **irregular plurals**.